# Retrieving an embedded object as a document via the aggregation framework in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a document, which contains an embedded object as a value of one of its fields, like this:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("..."), embeddedObject: { k1: "val1", k2: "val2", k3: "val3" } }
```

then how can I retrieve the embedded object itself as an output document with aggregation framework (pipeline operators)? Or it's not possible?

I.e., I need finally to get just the following result:

```
{ k1: "val1", k2: "val2", k3: "val3" }
```

Although operators $project, $match, $unwind, $group solve the close issues,  none of them seems to be able to help precisely with my aforementioned request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using one the aggregation pipeline operator [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

```
  db.[collection].aggregate( [
       {
         $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$embeddedObject" }
       }
    ] );
```

This will result in below output :

```
{ k1: "val1", k2: "val2", k3: "val3" }
```

Comment: Superb. Helped. Exactly what I needed. Thanks for a prompt reply!